# LXD: Shared Host Directory Permission Issues

Tags: lxd

*This is a copy of a similar post on the LXD fourms here:https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/shared-host-directory-permission-issues/ *

Hi there, I'm new to using LXD so please bear with me if this question has already been answered or is very simple.

I've been trying to set up a shared host directory between my webserver container, running NextCloud, and my host. I've tried

```
sudo chown 100000:100000 /hdd-pool/nextcloud_data
lxc config device add webserver test disk source ="/hdd-pool/nextcloud_data" path= "/nextcloud_data"
```

and verified through `ls -l /hdd-pool` that indeed `uid:100000` is in fact the owner. However, when I use `ls -l /nextcloud_data` in the container, it says that the shared directory belongs to `nobody` and `nogroup`.

I thought maybe since `hdd-pool` in my environment is actually a zpool mounted to `hdd-pool` that maybe that would have something to do with it. To test this, I created a test directory in my home directory with similar steps from above, but same results.

I've already looked into the following posts:
[Adding a shared host directory to an LXC/LXD Container](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691039/adding-a-shared-host-directory-to-an-lxc-lxd-container)

https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/shared-directory-between-lxd-containers/1982/2

https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/4h0erv/resolving_permissions_issues_with_host_bind/

and still don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Am I missing something in the config or documentation? Is there a better way to go about my setup? I'd also rather not make the container a privileged one...

Thanks in advance!

Eugene Seubert

Edit: changed `chmod` to `chown`

Comment: First:  You used the wrong command: `chmod` changes permissions instead of ownership. The chmod command should have (correctly) returned an error: `chmod: invalid mode: ‘100000:100000’`

Comment: Second: That [askubuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691039) is three years old, and much has changed. You should not need to `chown` anymore - the `lxc` command, done correctly, should set ownership and permissions properly withing the container.

Comment: @user535733 sorry, I meant chown. Any idea what might be causing the issue now then?

Comment: Did you chown the host dir back to what it originally was.

Comment: @user535733 yes, I've also created new directories to test and tried it again with no avail...

Comment: Have you used chown on the dir that's *inside* the container?

Comment: @user535733 Yes, it returns operation not permitted.

Comment: @user535733 I think I actually found the issue after doing some testing and research. Turns out that I installed the snap package of LXD instead of the deb package, which according to this post on the lxd forums: https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/snap-lxd-how-to-restart-lxd-without-restarting-containers/5259/2, doesn't use the `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid`. Do you know if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default container root user is 1000000
The default ubuntu user is 1001000

Your post indicates 100000 which is one 0 short.

Done it myself many times ;-)